# Pass activity from Activity to Broadcast Receiver

Tags: java, android

I need to pass activity instance to call method that stops AlarmManager.

MainActivity

```
    private void setAlarm(long timeInMilis) {
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService((Context.ALARM_SERVICE));
    MyAlarm myAlarm = new MyAlarm(this);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, myAlarm.getClass());
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, timeInMilis, 10000, pendingIntent);
    if (dbHelper.getProfile().getHp() >= 100) {
        stopAlarmManager();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Your character is fully healed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public void stopAlarmManager() {
    if (alarmManager != null)
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
}
```

and my BroadcastReceiver

```
public class MyAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

MainActivity mainActivity;

public MyAlarm() {
}

public MyAlarm(MainActivity mainActivity) {
    this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
    dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();


    dbHelper.setHp("1", dbHelper.getProfile().getHp() + 40);
    String currentHp = String.valueOf(dbHelper.getProfile().getHp());
    if (Integer.parseInt(currentHp) < dbHelper.getProfile().getHpMax())
        Toast.makeText(context, "Your character gain 40HP and now has: " + currentHp + "HP", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Your character is fully healed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mainActivity.stopAlarmManager();
    }
}
}
```

but this piece of code causes Error: **Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<(...) MainActivity.stopAlarmManager> on a null object reference**

Comment: In which method do you create MyAlarm instance? At which line do you receive the error message?

Comment: If I add no-arg constructor then I get an error at mainActivity.stopAlarmManager(); because of null object reference

Comment: can you show stopAlarmManager method code.

Comment: Ok I have added.

Comment: "I need to pass activity instance to call method that stops AlarmManager." – No, you don't. You just need a `Context` to get `AlarmManager`, and the same
`PendingIntent`. A `Context` is passed into your Receiver's `onReceive()` method, and the same `PendingIntent` can be made just by constructing it exactly as you did when you set the alarm.

Comment: If can make stopAlarmManager method static in MainActivity and then call it like MainActivity.stopAlarmManager(). You don't need main activity object.

Comment: @AmitTiwary it causes error "Non static field cannot be referenced from static context".

Comment: @MikeM. Could you please show me how should I do that? I do ((MainActivity)context).stopAlarmManager(); in my onReceive method but it gives error "java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext cannot be cast to MainActivity"

Comment: You won't be using `MainActivity` at all, there. You can get the `AlarmManager` in `onReceive()` like so: `alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(...);`. Then create the same `PendingIntent` that you did in the `setAlarm()` method, substituting `context` for `this`: `Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyAlarm.class);`, `pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);`. Then just cancel it from `onReceive()` directly: `alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);`.

Comment: Ok I will try but what means (...) in your code? Is it Context.ALARM_SERVICE?

Comment: Yes, that's it. I just omitted that so my comment would fit.